# Docker compose command script

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose for a code studio container. Because I want to use the terraform module and also the powershell, I have wrote a .sh that will install those programs in the container once it starts.

This is part of the code that will map the folder with the script and the command:

```
        volumes:
        - ./config:/config
        - ./script:/var/opt
    ports:
        - 8443:8443
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: /bin/sh -c "/var/opt/install.sh"
    networks:
```

When I run the `docker-compose up -d` it starts the script correctly, but after this, the container reboots.
I have edited the bash with the following lines just to confirm that it is not a code problem: (install.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"
```

And the problem persists. It shows the 'hello' and after this, reboots.
Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at [`command`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#command) from the official docs:

> Override the default command.
>
> ```
> command: bundle exec thin -p 3000
> ```
>
> The command can also be a list, in a manner similar to [dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):
>
> ```
> command: ["bundle", "exec", "thin", "-p", "3000"]
> ```

That means that when you set `command: /bin/sh -c "/var/opt/install.sh"` your container will run that script and then exit. That's what's causing it to reboot: the script has a defined point at which it exits (the end of the script, after it has installed the dependencies).

You'll notice in the command example from the docs that I pasted above they are demonstrating daemons that do not have a defined exit point. `bundle exec thin` will start a web server that will run indefinitely.

You will need to install your dependencies elsewhere, for example as a `RUN` step in your `Dockerfile` (but there isn't enough information here to tell you exactly what you should be doing to install those dependencies, and that answer is outside the scope of your question).